# how to achieve hover effect on phone react

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a code that changes another `div`'s `backgroundImage` when it it is hovered over. To do this, I use `onMouseOver={() => setCurrentIndex(i)}` and it does the job fine for laptops. However, onMouseOver does not seem to be working on phones until I have already clicked on the image/link, making it redundant.

```js
<Link key={post.node.title} href={`/posts/${post.node.slug}`}>
  <a
    onMouseOver={() => setCurrentIndex(i)}
    className={`p-2 border-r-2 h-full md:p-6 lg:p-8  ${currentIndex !== i ? 'opacity-70' : 'opacity-100'}`}
  >
    <div className="flex flex-col items-start h-full justify-end hover:-translate-y-4 ease-in-out duration-100 ">
      {post.node.categories.map((category) => (
        <Link passHref key={category.name} href={`/categories/${category.name}`}>
          <span className="hidden md:inline-block bg-gray-200 hover:bg-blue-100 ease-in duration-150 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2 mb-2">
            #{category.name}
          </span>
        </Link>
      ))}
      <h1 className="text-xs text-gray-200 font-bold md:text-3xl">{post.node.title}</h1>
    </div>
  </a>
</Link>
```

Comment: Replace this to be on click event

Comment: Mobile devices generally won't have mouse events. Try using pointer events as they are an attempt to unify mouse and touch events. Pointer events, OFC, have their own quirks.

Comment: _Socratic:_ How would you hover with your finger and how do you expect that your phone would know that you're hovering?

Comment: @jsejcksn I know it doesnt make much sense but when I have the hover utility class from tailwind and touch or scroll an element with it, it achieves the effect I am intending to do. In this case, we are not really hovering but the action is analogous to the effect. I do not want the user to click, as it will trigger the link, a simple glide over the element is all

Answer (score 0):

You can't use hover effects on mobile since there's no cursor.

If you want visual feedback for pressing a button do a click event with a ripple effect.

Something like this [Pure css ripple with minimal effort](https://codepen.io/finnhvman/post/pure-css-ripple-with-minimal-effort)

```
 /* Ripple effect */
.ripple {
  background-position: center;
  transition: background 0.8s;
}
.ripple:hover {
  background: #47a7f5 radial-gradient(circle, transparent 1%, #47a7f5 1%) center/15000%;
}
.ripple:active {
  background-color: #6eb9f7;
  background-size: 100%;
  transition: background 0s;
}

/* Button style */
button {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 12px 18px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  background-color: #2196f3;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px #999;
  outline: none;
}
```